maven spring viewresolver not showing jsp with 404
I have spring boot project as child project of a parent pom that serves jsp pages.
when I build (mvn clean install) the project from parent directory and start the jar (java -jar myproject) it gives me 404.
Everything works fine when I mvn clean install project and start it (java -jar myproject) from the UI project (child module) directly.
what could be the issue prevent spring boot jar to serve jsps pages?
I tried to build and run the project from parent pom and I was expecting it to serve the JSP pages
parent pom
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


4.0.0
<groupId>net.sub.nu</groupId>
<artifactId>nu-v2</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>nu-v2</name>
<description>PMS/description>

<modules>
    <module>nu-common</module>
    <module>nu-api</module>
    <module>nu-sched</module>
    <module>nu-pages</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring.boot.version>2.7.3</spring.boot.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.24</lombok.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>8.0.28</mysql.connector.version>
    <jxb.version>2.3.0</jxb.version>
    <redisson.version>3.17.6</redisson.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
    <jackson.version>2.12.3</jackson.version>
    <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <argLine>--enable-preview</argLine>
    <kotlin.version>1.9.0</kotlin.version>
</properties>



<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.unimi.dsi</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastutil</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jool</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.knowm</groupId>
            <artifactId>sundial</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
            <artifactId>vavr</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
            <artifactId>vavr-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
     
        </dependency>

        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230227</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-jre8</artifactId>
            <version>2.27.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.mockk</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockk</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.javaee-api</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jws</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.esotericsoftware</groupId>
            <artifactId>kryo</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.github.git-commit-id</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                    <commitIdGenerationMode>full</commitIdGenerationMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xallow-result-return-type</arg>
                        <arg>-Xno-param-assertions</arg>
                        <arg>-Xno-call-assertions</arg>
                    </args>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProperties>
                        <java.version>${java.version}</java.version>
                    </additionalProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.ozsie</groupId>
                <artifactId>detekt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.19.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <report>
                        <report>txt:reports/detekt.txt</report>
                        <report>xml:reports/detekt.xml</report>
                    </report>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals><goal>check</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <jvmTarget>${maven.compiler.target}</jvmTarget>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <mvn.profile.name>local</mvn.profile.name>
            <log.base.path>/tmp</log.base.path>
            <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            <server.port>9091</server.port>
            <springdoc.api-docs.enabled>true</springdoc.api-docs.enabled>


        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
            <mvn.profile.name>test</mvn.profile.name>
            <log.base.path>/tmp</log.base.path>
            <spring.profiles.active>test</spring.profiles.active>
            <server.port>9091</server.port>
            <springdoc.api-docs.enabled>false</springdoc.api-docs.enabled>

           
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <mvn.profile.name>dev</mvn.profile.name>
            <log.base.path>/var/log</log.base.path>
            <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            <server.port>9091</server.port>
            <springdoc.api-docs.enabled>true</springdoc.api-docs.enabled>

           

        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>stg</id>
        <properties>
            <mvn.profile.name>stg</mvn.profile.name>
            <log.base.path>/var/log</log.base.path>
            <spring.profiles.active>stg</spring.profiles.active>
            <server.port>9091</server.port>
            <springdoc.api-docs.enabled>true</springdoc.api-docs.enabled>

            

        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <mvn.profile.name>prod</mvn.profile.name>
            <log.base.path>/var/log</log.base.path>
            <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
            <server.port>9091</server.port>
            <springdoc.api-docs.enabled>false</springdoc.api-docs.enabled>

            

        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <properties>
            <sonar.host.url>
                http://nu.sonar.net
            </sonar.host.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

child ui (pages module)

4.0.0

net.sub.nu
nu-v2
1.0.0

nu-pages
1.0.0
jar
nu-pages
nu-pages
<properties>
    <java.version>18</java.version>
    <spring.boot.version>3.3.2</spring.boot.version>
    <jackson.version>2.14.2</jackson.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>10.1.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
        <artifactId>redisson-spring-data-33</artifactId>
        <version>3.34.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
        <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
        <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sub.nu</groupId>
        <artifactId>nu-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>net.sub.nu.pages.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


Please show us what you've tried so far. BR

Roar S. added POM, for character limit I remove few dependencies like fastutils

From project root: Run mvn clean -pl nu-pages -am install for building the jar. You should now have a runnable jar below nu-pages/target. BR

yes but this does not serve my jsp pagesm when I cd to nu pages and do mvn clean install everything works fine and jsp pages are served. I want mvn clean -pl nu-pages -am install to serve jsp pages I don't want to do clean install for nu-pages again
